# How to avoid element height shift in ScrollView (React Native) when element changes size?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am using a classical React Native ScrollView and my elements can change size on some user defined interaction. The element changes size because some new information is added on the top of the element (see pseudo-code below).

```
<View>
   {condition && (<View> Additional Info </View>)}
   <View> Original Element </View>
</View>
```

When this happens, I want to keep the Original Element to keep its position on the user's screen. However, and logically, the Original Element is visually shifted downwards because of the size change.

One solution that I could think of would be to manually scroll the view downwards as the additional info appears but it seems like a hack and I'm not confident about the visual rendering.

Can someone think of a better way to do this ?

Comment: This also feels hacky, but have you tried adding bottom padding to the scroll view at the same time as you add your new element?